# How Can I Use Custom Validation Attributes on Child Models of a DB Entity?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, data-annotations, dbcontext

**Summary:**

I want a data annotation validator to reference another property in the same class (`TitleAuthorAndPublishingConfiguration`).

However, DB.SaveChanges() is not being called on this class directly. Rather it is being called on the parent of this class (`WebsiteConfiguration`).

Therefore `validationContext.ObjectType` is returning `WebsiteConfiguration` and I am unable to refer to properties of `TitleAuthorAndPublishingConfiguration` within the data annotation validator.

---

**WebsiteConfiguration.cs**

```
public class WebsiteConfiguration
{
    [Key]
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public int ID { get; set; }

    public TitleAuthorAndPublishingConfiguration TitleAuthorAndPublishing { get; set; }

    public BookChaptersAndSectionsConfiguration BookChaptersAndSections { get; set; }

    public SocialMediaLoginsConfiguration SocialMediaLogins { get; set; }

    public TagGroupsConfiguration TagGroups { get; set; }
}

public class TitleAuthorAndPublishingConfiguration 
{
    public string BookTitle { get; set; }

    public bool IsPublished { get; set; }

    // how do I access a property of current model when calling DB.SaveChanges() on parent?
    [RequiredIfOtherFieldIsEnabled("IsPublished")]
    public string Publisher { get; set; }
}

// ... and other sub models...
```

**ApplicationDbContext.cs**

```
DbSet<WebsiteConfiguration> WebsiteConfiguration {get;set;}
```

**Example Update Code**

```
    public void SeedWebsiteConfiguration()
    {
        var titleAuthorAndPublishingConfiguration = new TitleAuthorAndPublishingConfiguration()
        {
            // seed values
        };
        var bookChaptersAndSectionsConfiguration = new BookChaptersAndSectionsConfiguration()
        {
            // seed values
        };
        var socialMediaLoginConfiguration = new SocialMediaLoginsConfiguration()
        {
            // seed values
        };
        var tagGroupsConfiguration = new TagGroupsConfiguration()
        {
            // seed values
        };
        var websiteConfiguration = new WebsiteConfiguration()
        {
            TitleAuthorAndPublishing = titleAuthorAndPublishingConfiguration,
            BookChaptersAndSections = bookChaptersAndSectionsConfiguration,
            SocialMediaLogins = socialMediaLoginConfiguration,
            TagGroups = tagGroupsConfiguration
        };
        DB.WebsiteConfiguration.Add(websiteConfiguration);
        DB.SaveChanges();
    }
```

---

**Validator Code**

```
public class RequiredIfOtherFieldIsEnabledAttribute : ValidationAttribute
{
    private string _ifWhatIsEnabled { get; set; }


    public RequiredIfOtherFieldIsEnabledAttribute(string IfWhatIsEnabled)
    {
        _ifWhatIsEnabled = IfWhatIsEnabled;
    }

    protected override ValidationResult IsValid(object currentPropertyValue, ValidationContext validationContext)
    {
        var isEnabledProperty = validationContext.ObjectType.GetProperty(_ifWhatIsEnabled);
        if (isEnabledProperty == null)
        {
            return new ValidationResult(
                string.Format("Unknown property: {0}", _ifWhatIsEnabled)
            );
        }
        var isEnabledPropertyValue = (bool)isEnabledProperty.GetValue(validationContext.ObjectInstance, null);

        if (isEnabledPropertyValue == true)
        {
            if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(currentPropertyValue.ToString()))
            {
                return new ValidationResult(String.Format("This field is required if {0} is enabled", isEnabledProperty));
            }
        }
        return ValidationResult.Success;
    }
}
```

---

**Questions**

1. Is there a way for me to access child model properties from `validationContext`?
2. Am I misguided in my approach?   Is there a better way to store multiple models as part of a larger model in a single DB table?

I was hoping not to have multiple config tables and calls to the DB. (There are 4 child models in this example, but there may be 10+ in the next app.)

The setup above meets my needs in so many ways. But I don't want to give up the functionality of DataAnnotations on the sub models!

---

**Bonus Question**

I have come across a few posts like this one: 
[How can I tell the Data Annotations validator to also validate complex child properties?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2493800/how-can-i-tell-the-data-annotations-validator-to-also-validate-complex-child-pro)

But that is 4 years old, and I'm wondering if anything has changed since then.

*Am I trying to do something that is basically impossible (or at least very difficult)?*

Comment: I want a data annotation validator on a property of `TitleAuthorAndPublishingConfiguration` to reference another property of `TitleAuthorAndPublishingConfiguration`. But `DB.SaveChanges()` is not being called on this class directly, rather on it's parent - `WebsiteConfiguration`.

Comment: I have updated the question, hopefully to make it clearer

Comment: Do you actually have the `TitleAuthorAndPublishingConfiguration` validator?

Comment: I added the validator code to the question - is that what you meant?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Am I trying to do something that is basically impossible (or at least
>   very difficult)?

No, there is a very simple solution that integrates perfectly with the framework and technologies using DataAnnotations.

You can create a custom `ValidationAttribute` that is called by EF Validation and call `Validator.TryValidateObject` inside. This way, when `CustomValidation.IsValid` is called by EF you launch child complex object validation by hand and so on for the whole object graph. As a bonus, you can gather all errors thanks to `CompositeValidationResult`.

i.e.

```
using System;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
using System.Collections.Generic;

public class Program
{
    public static void Main() {
   var person = new Person {
      Address = new Address {
         City = "SmallVille",
         State = "TX",
         Zip = new ZipCode()
      },
      Name = "Kent"
   };

   var context = new ValidationContext(person, null, null);
   var results = new List<ValidationResult>();

   Validator.TryValidateObject(person, context, results, true);

   PrintResults(results, 0);

   Console.ReadKey();
}

private static void PrintResults(IEnumerable<ValidationResult> results, Int32 indentationLevel) {
   foreach (var validationResult in results) {
      Console.WriteLine(validationResult.ErrorMessage);
      Console.WriteLine();

      if (validationResult is CompositeValidationResult) {
         PrintResults(((CompositeValidationResult)validationResult).Results, indentationLevel + 1);
      }
   }
}

}

public class ValidateObjectAttribute: ValidationAttribute {
   protected override ValidationResult IsValid(object value, ValidationContext validationContext) {
      var results = new List<ValidationResult>();
      var context = new ValidationContext(value, null, null);

      Validator.TryValidateObject(value, context, results, true);

      if (results.Count != 0) {
         var compositeResults = new CompositeValidationResult(String.Format("Validation for {0} failed!", validationContext.DisplayName));
         results.ForEach(compositeResults.AddResult);

         return compositeResults;
      }

      return ValidationResult.Success;
   }
}

public class CompositeValidationResult: ValidationResult {
   private readonly List<ValidationResult> _results = new List<ValidationResult>();

   public IEnumerable<ValidationResult> Results {
      get {
         return _results;
      }
   }

   public CompositeValidationResult(string errorMessage) : base(errorMessage) {}
   public CompositeValidationResult(string errorMessage, IEnumerable<string> memberNames) : base(errorMessage, memberNames) {}
   protected CompositeValidationResult(ValidationResult validationResult) : base(validationResult) {}

   public void AddResult(ValidationResult validationResult) {
      _results.Add(validationResult);
   }
}

public class Person {
  [Required]
  public String Name { get; set; }

  [Required, ValidateObject]
  public Address Address { get; set; }
}

public class Address {
  [Required]
  public String Street1 { get; set; }

  public String Street2 { get; set; }

  [Required]
  public String City { get; set; }

  [Required]
  public String State { get; set; }

  [Required, ValidateObject]
  public ZipCode Zip { get; set; }
}

public class ZipCode {
  [Required]
  public String PrimaryCode { get; set; }

  public String SubCode { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Thank you.  I will give that a go.